# Why did Arthur Weasley prefer Portkey rather than Apparition?

Tags: harry-potter

The Weasleys along with Harry and Hermione could have Side-Along Apparated to the Quidditch World Cup, There are four licenced and professional practitioners (Arthur, Bill, Charlie, Percy) in Weasley's.

**Why did they use a less comfortable way of Portkeys to the  Quidditch World Cup?**

> “Some Apparate, of course, but we have to set up safe points for them to appear, well away from Muggles. I believe there's a handy wood they're using as the Apparition point.”
>
> <sub>- *Harry Potter and The Goblet of Fire*, Chapter 6-*The Portkey*</sub>

We can see that underage wizards can Side-Along Apparate without any mess with Ministry of Magic from Harry's Apparition with Dumbledore

> “You have not, of course, passed your Apparition Test,” he said.
>
> “No,” said Harry.
>
> “I thought you had to be seventeen?”
>
> “You do,” said Dumbledore.
>
> “So you will need to hold on to my arm very tightly. My left, if you don’t mind — as you have noticed, my wand arm is a little fragile at the moment.”
>   Harry gripped Dumbledore’s proffered forearm.
>
> “Very good,” said Dumbledore. “Well, here we go.”
>
> <sub>- *Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince*, Chapter 4-*Horace Slughorn*</sub>

Comment: Is "because a portkey would be a plot point later in the novel, and we want to get the explaining out of the way now" be an acceptable answer?

Comment: + meeting the Diggorys for the first time.